# select top 1 with a group by

Tags: sql-server

I have two columns:

```
namecode name
050125  chris
050125  tof
050125  tof
050130  chris
050131  tof
```

I want to group by namecode, and return only the name with the most number of occurrences. In this instance, the result would be

```
050125  tof
050130  chris
050131  tof
```

This is with SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT max_table.namecode, count_table2.name
FROM
    (SELECT namecode, MAX(count_name) AS max_count
     FROM
         (SELECT namecode, name, COUNT(name) AS count_name
          FROM mytable
          GROUP BY namecode, name) AS count_table1
     GROUP BY namecode) AS max_table
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT namecode, COUNT(name) AS count_name, name
     FROM mytable
     GROUP BY namecode, name) count_table2
ON max_table.namecode = count_table2.namecode AND
   count_table2.count_name = max_table.max_count
```

Answer (score 13):

I usually use `ROW_NUMBER()` to achieve this.  Not sure how it performs against various data sets, but we haven't had any performance issues as a result of using `ROW_NUMBER`.

The `PARTITION BY` clause specifies which value to "group" the row numbers by, and the `ORDER BY` clause specifies how the records within each "group" should be sorted.  So partition the data set by NameCode, and get all records with a Row Number of 1 (that is, the first record in each partition, ordered by the `ORDER BY` clause).

```
SELECT 
    i.NameCode, 
    i.Name
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.NameCode ORDER BY t.Name),
        t.NameCode,
        t.Name
    FROM
        MyTable t
) i
WHERE
    i.RowNumber = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct namecode
, (
     select top 1 name from 
            (
             select namecode, name, count(*) 
             from myTable i
             where i.namecode = o.namecode
             group by namecode, name 
             order by count(*) desc
            ) x
) as name
from myTable o
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not try but this should work,

```
select top 1 t2.* from (
select namecode, count(*) count from temp 
group by namecode) t1 join temp t2 on t1.namecode = t2.namecode 
order by t1.count desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are to examples that you could use but the temp table use is more efficient than the view, but was done on a small data sample.  You would want to check your own statistics.

```
    --Creating A View
GO
CREATE VIEW StateStoreSales AS
SELECT t.state,t.stor_id,t.stor_name,SUM(s.qty) 'TotalSales'
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.state ORDER BY SUM(s.qty) DESC) AS 'Rank'
FROM [dbo].[sales] s
JOIN [dbo].[stores] t ON (s.stor_id = t.stor_id)
GROUP BY t.state,t.stor_id,t.stor_name

GO
SELECT * FROM StateStoreSales
WHERE Rank <= 1
ORDER BY TotalSales Desc

DROP VIEW StateStoreSales


---Using a Temp Table
SELECT t.state,t.stor_id,t.stor_name,SUM(s.qty) 'TotalSales'
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.state ORDER BY SUM(s.qty) DESC) AS 'Rank'     INTO #TEMP
FROM [dbo].[sales] s
JOIN [dbo].[stores] t ON (s.stor_id = t.stor_id)
GROUP BY t.state,t.stor_id,t.stor_name

SELECT * FROM #TEMP
WHERE Rank <= 1
ORDER BY TotalSales Desc

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```