# How to replace function with a view in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have been in a strange situation i m using a function is to retrieve the top 1 record from a particular table. But using function is killing the performance of my query as the table have more than 50,000 record. i want to know how can i replace that function with a view and then join it into a stored procedure so i can get better performance. here is the code that i have  written in the function

```
Create function getlatestusernote(@warrantid varchar(20))      
Returns varchar(300)    
As       
Begin       
Declare @latestnote  VARCHAR(300)    
SELECT TOP 1 @latestnote= Remarks FROM Warrant_notes WHERE WarrantID = @warrantid AND NotesCat <>0 ORDER BY NoteDate  desc    
return @latestnote      
END
```

Not i want to have a view for the same query kindly help me to figure out this problem.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I've removed the C# tag from your question as I am not sure it is relevant. Apologies if you actually needed it.

Comment: Just join the table with the others.

Comment: I don't think `asp.net` and `.net` tags are relevant either.

Comment: @bansi You are right. I removed those too. To the op, again, if you needed those, please add them again and explain why they are relevant. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have indexes on `WarrantID` and `NotesCat` columns?

Comment: why not just use plain SELECT for this and JOIN it with the other tables if needed? you only get 1 record out of that function even if you use a view it still going to be the same.

Comment: if i use the view it did not giving the desired output because its selecting the only one record in the table. what i want to do a filter in a view @Saechel

Comment: Then remove the TOP 1. That limits your query to only 1 record. @Nitin Singh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took this from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793054/select-top-1-with-a-group-by/14165900#14165900) top rated (albeit unaccepted) answer (which you should look into to better understand what's going on) to another question and adapted it. Of course, I have no way to test this, but I believe this looks right. Let me know if it doesn't work and I can help troubleshoot.

You should be able to create your view based on this, then query against that.

```
SELECT WarrantID, Remarks
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.WarrantID ORDER BY t.NoteDate DESC),
        t.Remarks,
        t.WarrantID
    FROM
        Warrant_notes t
    WHERE NotesCat <> 0
) i
WHERE i.RowNumber = 1;
```