# Sql Get Latest Records With Specific Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this data

```
UserId   LoginTime     Machine
100       1.1.2022        A
100       1.2.2022        B
101       1.3.2022        C
101       1.4.2022        D
101       1.5.2022        E
```

and I need this output by sql query

```
UserId     LoginTime    Machine
100         1.2.2022       B
101         1.5.2022       E
```

The latest records grouping by UserId and including Machine info

I tried group by and max functions but I need Machine info and when I try group by, results doesn't show up as single, because machine info is different.
Could you help me with this query?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793054/select-top-1-with-a-group-by) answer your question? In your case you would use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY LoginTime DESC)`

Answer (score 1):

use row_number()

```
select b.* from (select a.*, row_number() over(partition by userid order by logintime desc) rn
from table_name a) b where b.rn=1
```